# Nativescript: How to disable button text from default text opacity on highlighted state

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I have Button element and I want to disable the default opacity fade of the Button text when the Button is pressed.  I tried to override the behavior by using the pseudoselector `:highlighted { opacity: 1; }` but it didn't do anything.

Comment: The button color should be set using `: highlighted` pseudoselector.

Comment: @Manoj I could control the color with the pseudoselector but even if I made the color 'green', it wouldn't truly be green since there is an opacity on it by default.  I'm trying to override that somehow.

Comment: I tried that for ios.:highlighted { opacity: 0.1; } or :highlighted { opacity: 1; } and it works but to certain extent. Looks like there is some default code to manage the transparemcy when 'pressed' and after that limit opacity works

Comment: @Barnus Could you please confirm whether it's iOS specific?